# No internet on raspberry pi

Tags: ssh, internet-connection, raspberry-pi

I am trying to SSH into a rapberry pi, and my internet does not seem to be working. I am using my laptop to bridge a wifi to ethernet, which feeds into the raspberry pi. When I try to use ifconfig to find out my ip address, the result is

```
eth0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:--:--:--:--
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 METRIC:1
        RX packets:321 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 carrier: 0
        TX paclets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
        RX bytes:28004 (27.3 KiB) TX bytes:0 (0.0B)

Io      Link encap:local loopback
        inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
        UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
        RX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 evverruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
        RX bytes 100 (100.0 B) TX bytes:100 (100.0B)
```

If i could get some help with this, it would be greatly appreciated. I have tried basically everything else out there on the internet.

Comment: looks like you don't have a DHCP server on that ethernet network. try configuring the raspi to use a static IP.

Comment: how would i configure it to use a static ip?

Comment: quick and dirty: `ifconfig eth0 add 10.11.12.13 up` (for 10.11.12.13 being the static ip to use). to be reboot-proof, you should refer to your distribution manual, usually theres a `/etc/network/interfaces` file or something similar.

Comment: once i do that my internet still does not work and my raspberry pi still cannot be reached at that address through putty. I might be missing something as I am a complete computer noob, but what am I missing?

Comment: does it at least show the IP in ifconfig now?

Comment: you need to set the "gateway" to the eth0 interface

Comment: @nonchip it does show the ip in ifconfig now, but it is under the name of eth0:0, seperate from the eth0 name

Comment: @Logman how would i set the gateway, i cannot even find the gateway, because my kernal ip routing table is empty

Comment: *"No internet..."* -- Your local network is not the Internet.  You need to establish a LAN connection to your (wired/wireless) router before you can consider any Internet access. You should not assign a static IP address without first knowing the subnet that other hosts are using in your LAN (and the IP addresses already in use). If you use a static IP address within the subnet, then you do not have to specify the gateway address within the LAN.  **`eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr b8:27:--:--:--:--`** Is that what is actually displayed, or are you just trying to hide the MAC address?

Comment: from the raspberryPI type this: ```sudo dhclient eth0``` if there's a DHCP on your network the PI will ask for an IP. Then run ```ifconfig``` again and check if eth0 got an IP.